# How to use react-native-offline package in App?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist, offline-mode

I want to implement offline support in my existing react native App. I have use redux , redux-persist and redux-thunk in app. react-native-offline package not given a proper example for redux-persist and redux-thunk that how to implement. I did try to implement but not got success. if anyone implement these thing so direct me how to create action, dispatch and and store. and how to set api in queue while mobile don't have internet connection and how to execute queue when user found internet connection.